# Problem running KDE in ArchLinux: "x" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes

Tags: linux, vmware, kde, arch-linux

I am looking into Arch-Linux so I created a VMWare install of it. Unfortunately, I can't seem to be getting KDE to run. It claims that KDE is starting at boot, but it is followed by "x" respawning too fast: disabled for 5 minutes. KDM is running when I enter `ps -A`;

I have this in inittab:

```
id:5:initdefault:
x:5:respawn:/usr/bin/kdm -nodaemon
```

And I have this in /etc/rc.conf:

```
DAEMONS=(hwclock syslog-ng dbus network netfs crond kdm)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have only one command to start kdm, either the one in rc.conf or the one in inittab.

The inittab method is preferred as it would respawn the kdm in case of crashes (according to archwiki: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Display_Manager).

Comment: That got rid of an error message, but I'm still having difficulty. I'll give you the answer though if I don't get anything in the next day or so.

Comment: @cwallenpoole: What is the difficulty you are having now?